# mConstraintSet.clone(mConstraintLayout); Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraintLayout nested inside a ScrollView which is nested inside a drawerLayout as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android=...[snip]>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width=...[snip]>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

In the constraintLayout I have an imageView with xml as below:

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/remotePokerCard2"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="88dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cardSelectcontent"
                android:onClick="card2clicked"
                android:padding="3dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noOfPlayersTextView"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/pokercard2"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
```

**GOAL: I am trying to programmatically change my constraintTop_toBottomOf.**

From

```
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noOfPlayersTextView"
```

To

```
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/2ndImageView"
```

My Java Class `Class2` updates the UI every time there is a change in FireStore. `Class2` is being passed the activity context `passedActivity` from the parent Activity Class `Class1`. It is then setting up my ConstraintSet, and passing the `mConstraintSet` and `mConstraintLayout` to another Java class `Class3`.

**In Class1**

```
Activity passedActivity = Activity_RemotePoker.this;

callRemotePokerListener.Class2(passedActivity, selectedTeamName, TAG, methodName, true, cardNumber, alreadySelected);
```

**In Class2**

```
public void Class2(final Activity passedActivity, final String selectedTeam, final String TAG, final String methodName, final Boolean destroyDBListener, int cardNumber, Boolean alreadySelected){

[snip]

                            ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.constraintlayout);
                            ConstraintSet mConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
                            mConstraintSet.clone(mConstraintLayout);
                            callFastSizing.Class3(initialCount, TAG, passedActivity, cardSizes, mConstraintLayout, mConstraintSet);

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            }
        }
```

**EXPECTED RESULT: I have cloned my Activity_RemotePoker layout to mConstraintSet**

**ACTUAL RESULT: I keep throwing a null pointer exception when I try to clone the existing constraintLayout of the activity.**

```
mConstraintSet.clone(mConstraintLayout);
```

*"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet.clone(ConstraintSet.java:705)"*

**In Class3**

```
public class FastSizing {

public void Class3(int initialCount, String TAG, Activity passedActivity, ArrayList cardSizes, ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout, ConstraintSet mConstraintSet){

[snip]

            cardFastChoice.setVisibility(cardFastChoice.VISIBLE);
            mConstraintSet.connect(cardNumber2.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, cardFastChoice.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 24);
            mConstraintSet.applyTo(mConstraintLayout);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In Class2 you are using the wrong id to find your constraintLayout. Use ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);

Comment: Argh, dont know how I missed that! Thanks

Comment: Lol, we've all been there!